# ggplot not displayed in Shiny but works fromn the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

The following minimal Shiny app fails to display when I launch the app. The sidebar shows up but not the main panel. I get no error messages or warnings. The app just hangs there.

The ggplot works in the console.

This must be an environmental parameter controlling the interface between Shiny & ggplot2. But what is it. Have tried setting dev.off() to no avail. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
# client logo

# select trade
selectInput(inputId = "trade",
            label   = "Trade",
            choices = trades,
            selected = defaultTrade
)
),

mainPanel(
# performance time series plots
plotOutput(outputId = "tsPlotRev", height = "195px")


)
 )



server <- function(input, output) {(
output$tsPlotVol <- renderPlot(
  ggplot(data.frame(tsData), aes(x = as.Date(weekDate), y = as.numeric(revenue) / 1000000, color = as.factor(isHist))) +
    geom_line() + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "4 week", date_labels = "%y-%W") + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 0.75), legend.position = "none") + 
    labs(x = NULL, y = "revenue (million USD)")
)
)}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Try `plotOutput(outputId = "tsPlotVol", height = "195px")`. The `outputId` must correspond to the output name of the `renderPlot`.

Comment: Thank you Gregor. THis helped the immediate problem and the plots are showing up in the example.